# How to exclude more rows by one match

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, sorry but I don't know how to formulate the subject correctly.
That's why I'd better describe the issue.

I have a kind of following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Test` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `v1` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

INSERT INTO `Test` (`Name`, `v1`) 
  VALUES ('A', 4), ('A', 3), ('B', 6), ('C', 1), ('C', 2), 
         ('C', 7), ('D', 7), ('D', 5), ('E', 3), ('F', 1), 
         ('F', 2), ('G', 7), ('H', 9), ('H', 1), ('I', 5);
```

What I need is to find all names that matches e.g. 7.
These are `'C'`, `'D'` and `'G'`.

And now I need to select all rows except `'C'`, `'D'` and `'G'`.
Resulting table is supposed to be:

```
===============
| Name  | v1  |
|–––––––––––––|
|   A   |  4  |
|   A   |  3  |
|   B   |  6  |
|   E   |  3  |
|   F   |  1  |
|   F   |  2  |
|   H   |  9  |
|   H   |  1  |
|   I   |  5  |
|–––––––––––––|
```

I've tried the query:

```sql
select t1.Name, t1.v1
from `Test` as t1
join (
  select Name from `Test`
  where v1 = 7
  ) as t2
  on t1.Name != t2.Name
```

but only realized that I still do not understand the mechanics of `JOIN` statements.

Hope for some help with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE v1 = 7
```

returns all the `Name`s that you want to exclude.
Use it with the operator `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE v1 = 7)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d0cf366c82d49d4b7a8129d4244b111b).
Results:

```
> Id | Name | v1
> -: | :--- | -:
>  1 | A    |  4
>  2 | A    |  3
>  3 | B    |  6
>  9 | E    |  3
> 10 | F    |  1
> 11 | F    |  2
> 13 | H    |  9
> 14 | H    |  1
> 15 | I    |  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from test t
where not exists (select 1
                  from test t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.v1 = 7
                 );
```

This selects all rows in `test` where the name on the row has no row with `7`, anywhere in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with JOINs...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM test x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN test y 
    ON y.name = x.name 
   AND y.v1 = 7 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
+----+------+----+
| Id | Name | v1 |
+----+------+----+
|  1 | A    |  4 |
|  2 | A    |  3 |
|  3 | B    |  6 |
|  9 | E    |  3 |
| 10 | F    |  1 |
| 11 | F    |  2 |
| 13 | H    |  9 |
| 14 | H    |  1 |
| 15 | I    |  5 |
+----+------+----+
```